# Upgraded from .NETCore 3.1 to .NET 6 and now experiencing a 401 unauthorized error when the API is called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I am managing a legacy asp.net project. I had to recently upgrade from asp.net core 3.1 to 6.0. When I made this upgrade, the api backend doesn't seem to allow the front end to access the api. I am new to asp.net development and I did not create this project so I am at a loss on where or how to troubleshoot. My assumption is that something in the packages or implementation of the jwt and how they are read in must have changed in .Net6. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

**.csproj file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId></UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="11.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.8">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.Common.Hosting" Version="3.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.CloudFoundryCore" Version="3.2.1" /> <!---->
    <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigServerCore" Version="3.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.Security.Authentication.CloudFoundryCore" Version="3.2.1" /> <!---->
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentionFile>true</GenerateDocumentionFile>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\net6.0\csu.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Startup.cs file**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using csu.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
// using Steeltoe.CloudFoundry.Connector;
// using Steeltoe.CloudFoundry.Connector.Services;
using Steeltoe.Security.Authentication.CloudFoundry;
using Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.CloudFoundry;
using Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI;

namespace csu
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _CurrentEnvironment = env;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment _CurrentEnvironment { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOptions();

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                            .AddCloudFoundryJwtBearer(Configuration);

            // In case you want to get your client_id or auth_domain out of SSO Tile via Steeltoe, here it is:
            // var ssoInfo = Configuration.GetSingletonServiceInfo<SsoServiceInfo>();
            // csu.EnvironmentConfig.SsoTileClientId = ssoInfo.ClientId;
            // csu.EnvironmentConfig.SsoTileAuthDomain = ssoInfo.AuthDomain;

            services.Configure<Utils.ConfigurationData>(Configuration);
            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var configVariables = sp.GetService<IOptions<Utils.ConfigurationData>>().Value;

            var sqlbuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CSUConnection"));

            if (configVariables.UserID == null)
            {
                sqlbuilder.UserID = Configuration["CSU:UserID"];
                sqlbuilder.Password = Configuration["CSU:PWD"];
                sqlbuilder.InitialCatalog = Configuration["CSU:InitialCatalog"];
                sqlbuilder["Server"] = Configuration["CSU:Server"];
                sqlbuilder.TrustServerCertificate = true;
            }
            else
            {
                sqlbuilder.UserID = configVariables.UserID;
                sqlbuilder.Password = configVariables.Password;
                sqlbuilder.InitialCatalog = configVariables.InitialCatalog;
                sqlbuilder["Server"] = configVariables.Server;
                sqlbuilder.TrustServerCertificate = true;
            }

            services.AddDbContext<CSUContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer
                            (sqlbuilder.ConnectionString));

            services.AddDbContext<AuditContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer
                            (sqlbuilder.ConnectionString));

            //add in star context
            var sqlbuilderStar = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(Configuration.GetConnectionString("StarConnection"));

            if (configVariables.StarUserID == null)
            {
                sqlbuilderStar.UserID = Configuration["CSU:StarUserID"];
                sqlbuilderStar.Password = Configuration["CSU:StarPWD"];
                sqlbuilderStar.InitialCatalog = Configuration["CSU:StarInitialCatalog"];
                sqlbuilderStar["Server"] = Configuration["CSU:StarServer"];
                sqlbuilderStart.TrustServerCertificate = true;
            }
            else
            {
                sqlbuilderStar.UserID = configVariables.StarUserID;
                sqlbuilderStar.Password = configVariables.StarPassword;
                sqlbuilderStar.InitialCatalog = configVariables.StarInitialCatalog;
                sqlbuilderStar["Server"] = configVariables.StarServer;
                sqlbuilderStart.TrustServerCertificate = true;
            }

            services.AddDbContext<StarContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer
                            (sqlbuilderStar.ConnectionString));

            services.AddScoped<ICsuRepository, SQLServerRepo>();

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

            // services.AddControllers(); // Before using NewtonSoft Json Serialization
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(s =>
            {
                s.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                s.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });


            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1",
          new OpenApiInfo
          {
              Title = "Customer Support WebAPI",
              Description = "Provide an API with CRUD functionalities to support CSU"
          });

                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlFilePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlFilePath);
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Customer Support University WebAPI");
                // Use the below to allow methods in Swagger
                // options.SupportedSubmitMethods(new[] { SubmitMethod.Get });
                options.SupportedSubmitMethods();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Snippet from a controller method**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;
using csu.Data;
using csu.Dtos;
using csu.Models;
using csu.Utils;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace csu.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    public class CollegesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICsuRepository _repository;
        private IMapper _mapper;

        public CollegesController(ICsuRepository repository, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<CollegeReadDto>> GetAllColleges()
        {
            var colleges = _repository.GetAllColleges();

            return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CollegeReadDto>>(colleges));
        }

        [HttpGet("[action]/{workforceID}")]
        public ActionResult<CollegeReadDto> GetCollegesInWorkforce(int workforceID)
        {
            var workforce = _repository.GetWorkforce(workforceID);
            if (workforce != null)
            {
                List<CollegeReadDto> colleges = new List<CollegeReadDto>();
                foreach (var college in workforce.Colleges)
                {
                    colleges.Add(_mapper.Map<CollegeReadDto>(college));
                }
                return Ok(colleges);
            }
            return NotFound();
        }

...
```

I've tried updating the packages but still nothing. I get the below error.

```
HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
    csu_fe.Data.CSUClient.GetColleges() in CSUClient.cs

                    res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

csu_fe.Components.CollegeDropdownViewComponent.InvokeAsync() in CollegeDropdown.cs

                List<CollegeReadDto> colleges = await _client.GetColleges();

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentInvoker.InvokeAsyncCore(ObjectMethodExecutor executor, ViewComponentContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentInvoker.InvokeAsync(ViewComponentContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentHelper.InvokeCoreAsync(ViewComponentDescriptor descriptor, object arguments)
AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.<ExecuteAsync>b__35_1() in _Layout.cshtml

                                    @await Component.InvokeAsync("CollegeDropdown")

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.ExecuteAsync() in _Layout.cshtml

        Layout = null;

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|27_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
RolesMiddleWare.InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext) in RolesMiddleWare.cs

            await _next(httpContext);

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: The Steeltoe security references suggest that a UAA server or SSO provided by a Cloud Foundry-based platform (such as Tanzu Application Service) are part of this puzzle. Is that accurate? If so, are you seeing these failures locally or in a Cloud Foundry environment? Your program.cs might also be relevant in such a case

Comment: It may be worth reviewing the [Steeltoe samples](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/main/Security) for another angle on how those pieces can work. I've just pushed [a branch](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/security-refresh/Security) that updates to the minimal API style and has general improvements to usability. WIP because there are still updates to be made on the README/doc side